# Unable to get a block of code into my regex match groups

Tags: c#, regex, ironpython

So yeah, the title is pretty weird but I have no other idea how to describe my problem properly. Whatever... lets get to the problem.

#### **Job to get done**

My boss wants a function that read all functions of a python file and return a DataTable containing the found functions. This function should be written in IronPython (Python which actually uses C# libraries).

#### **The Problem**

I am relatively new to Python and I have no idea what this language is capable of, so I started to write my function and yeah it works pretty well, except one weird problem. I wrote a regular expression to find the functions and to test it I downloaded a RegEx Tester. The Regex Tester showed the results I wanted: Group 1 - The function name, Group 2 - The functions parameter and Group 3 - the content of the function.

For some magical reasons, it doesn't work when it goes to live testing. And with doesn't work I mean, Group 3 has actually no output. After testing the expression with another (online) [RegEx Tester](http://regexhero.net/tester/), it showed me, that Group 3 has actually not the content of the function, it only has a small part of it, starting with a newline/return character.

In my test cases, the results of Group 3 where all the same, starting with a newline/return character and ended with the functions *return* (e.g. return objDic).

Question: What the hell is going wrong there? I have no idea what is wrong on my RegEx.

#### **The Regex**

```
objRegex = Regex(r"(?i)def[\s]+([\w]+)\(([\, [\w]+)\)(?:[\:{1}]\s*)([\n].*(?!\ndef[\s]+))+")
```

#### **The Data**

```
def test_function(some_parameter):
    try:
        some_cool_code_goes_here()
        return obj
    except Exception as ex:
        DetailsBox.Show(ex)

def another_cool_function(another_parameter):
    try:
        what_you_want()
        return obj
    except Exception as ex:
        DetailsBox.Show(ex)
```

#### **The Result**

**Match:** def test_function(some_parameter):...
**Position:** ..
**Length:** ..
**Group 1:** test_function
**Group 2:** some_parameter
**Group 3:** *(newline/return character)*
return obj

But Group 3 should be:

```
    try:
        some_cool_code_goes_here()
        return obj
    except Exception as ex:
        DetailsBox.Show(ex)
```

I hope you can help me :3 Thank you guys!

Comment: There are several problems with your regex, I decided to rewrite it. I'm not sure if py supports named groups. [Take a look](http://regex101.com/r/bY1iX9). BTW +1 for the efforts you've put in making this question, it really encourages me to help.

Answer (score 2):

Although @Hamza said in his comment that you have several problems in your regex, I think they are more of uneeded complexity, the reason for not matching the body might be that you haven't let the `.` special meta-character match the new line so it is stopping at the first new line character after the first `Try:` statement.

To fix this you will need to let the `.` match new line characters and here is a stripped down version of your regex that works:

```
(?i)def\s+(\w+)\s*\(([\, \w]+)\)(?:\s*:\s*)(.+?)(?=def|$)
```

Comment: Yes, I am not that good into RegEx but I have learned a lot thanks to you guys.

Comment: You could also match newline characters with [\s\S] instead of .

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [HamZa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1401975/hamza) for the quick help (and of course also thanks for all the other helpers), he actually solved the problem. There were just a few adjustments necessary (to make it work for C# :-)) but the main point comes from him, thanks a lot.

Solution for my problem:

```
Regex(r"(?is)def\s*(?<name>\w+)\s*\((?<parameter>[^)]+)\)\s*:\s*(?:\r?\n)+(?<body>.*?)(?=\r?\ndef|$)")
```