# Matching a text which contains {word} but not {2ndword}

Tags: c#, python, regex

I wrote a regular expression (after some great help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232343/unable-to-get-a-block-of-code-into-my-regex-match-groups/18233011?noredirect=1#18233011)) which filters all functions from a python-file. So now, my boss wants only the functions which contains *OpenSession* but not *Session.Close()*.

I read the [article about Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), but to be honest, even after many times of reading it, I am not able to get use to it. But I think its a general lack of regex understanding. Whatever...

My tries failed all and the last one was: `(?is)def\s*(?<name>\w+)\s*\((?<parameter>[^)]+)\)\s*:\s*(?:\r?\n)+(?<body>(?<=OpenSession?).*?(?=Session\.Close?))(?=\r?\ndef|$)`

Can someone help me and maybe explain the steps, so I can learn from it?

Comment: Well, to make it easier, you could check for those specific conditions after obtaining all the functions.

Comment: Yeah, I'm already on it, but I think a regex version would be more "elegant" respectively shorter.

Comment: I don't think that's possible with a single regex, but the check can be done easily with two regex, one to check the presence of `OpenSession` and one to check any `Session.Close()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would certainly be easier (more readable, more maintable) to just get all functions and then filter them by whether they contain `OpenSession` and don't contain `Session.Close()`. It is possible though. I'm only focussing on the `body` part of your expression here. To check whether there's an `OpenSession` coming we put it into a look**ahead**. But the lookahead only checks at the current position, so we need to allow for arbitrarily many characters in between:

```
(?=.*OpenSession)
```

The problem is, this could find `OpenSession` in the next function. So we need to make sure that `.*` cannot go past the next `def`. To do that, before consuming each character, we need to check that it does not mark the beginning of a `def` (with another, *negative*  lookahead):

```
(?=(?:(?!def).)*OpenSession)
```

So now the pattern will not match a function, if it doesn't contain `OpenSession`. To rule out out functions that do contain `Session.Close`, we use a similar trick as we used inside the lookahead. We try to get to the next `def` without ever going beyond a `Session.Close`:

```
(?=(?:(?!def).)*OpenSession)(?:(?!Session[.]Close).)*?
```

The lookahead at the end of your original pattern will then ensure that you were able to consume the entire function body this way. Also note, that you can probably slightly improve performance, by avoiding the non-greedy repetition. You can do this by adding `def` to the second lookahead as well:

```
(?=(?:(?!\r?\ndef).)*OpenSession)(?:(?!Session[.]Close|\r?\ndef).)*
```

So the expression would look like:

```
(?is)def\s+(?<name>\w+)\s*\((?<parameter>[^)]+)\)\s*:\s*(?:\r?\n)+(?<body>(?=(?:(?!\r?\ndef).)*OpenSession)(?:(?!Session[.]Close|\r?\ndef).)*)(?=\r?\ndef|$)
```

I don't know what you wanted to accomplish with the `?` at the end of your lookarounds, but all they did was make the last character optional.

Also note that the pattern is generally a bit dangerous, because you might have a multiline string in the function, that contains `\ndef`, in which case the regex would not return the entire function.

As HamZa mentioned in a comment, you might want to put word boundaries `\b` around each `OpenSession`, `Session.Close` and `def`, so as not to trip up on `getOpenSession()`, `Session.Closed` and `define`.

Comment: Nice +1! I would also suggest to use word boundaries `\bOpenSession\b`

Comment: Indeed! Didn't occur to me to use `(?:(?!def).)*` to check each `.`.

Comment: @HamZa I actually thought about that... no idea why I didn't add it. Thanks, I've edited the answer ;)

Comment: I'm curious why you (a regex guru/ambassador) aren't using (and strongly recommending others use) free spacing mode with comments and indentation? Long, complex expressions (like the one above which requires a horizontal scroll bar and has parentheses nested four levels deep), are just plain _ugly_ (even if they do work). Just sayin'

Comment: @ridgerunner I usually do use free-spacing for complex patterns, but in all honesty, I couldn't be bothered to reformat the OPs pattern. I guess, I should have mentioned it though.

Comment: Fair enough (and I know what you mean). You're really going to like the new tool I'm getting ready to release: [RegexTidy](http://regextidy.org "May all Regular Expressions be tidy!") which is a simple one page javascript web app that takes a native regex input (PCRE flavor) and reformats it into free spacing mode with proper indentation and basic comments. I, too, got tired of trying to decipher some of the long, nasty regexes you see around here, so I decided to write this app to help make them readable. p.s. Your `def\s*` should probably be `def\s+`.

Comment: @ridgerunner Sounds good :). And yes, that should probably be a `+`. As I said, I just copied it and dumped in the adjusted bits.